# ActionMode won't apply theme when using Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, theming

I'm using Android's new widget `Toolbar`, and i want to change its ActionMode's background and text color (first strange thing : ActionMode won't use the default primary color, which it should be the default behavior ...).

I tried setting `android:actionModeBackground`, it works, but `actionModeStyle` won't apply `textColor`.

Any clue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this
    set actionModeBackground to @color/primary
    set actionBarPopupTheme to @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light

actionBarPopupTheme is your App parent theme